# Translate a angularJS Value with Symfony

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, translation

I'm using Symfony in my backend and render the templates via twig.
For translations I'm using following guide, which works fine.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

works:

```
{{ "Active Option" | trans({}, 'frontend', app.request.locale) }}
```

But the problem is, that I have some of the words, which I have to translate, are in angularJS variables.
I have multiple .xlf files for the translation and I know the angular.translate.
But I don't want to implement it.

```
{{ '{{' }} item.optionTitle {{ '}}' | trans({}, 'option', app.request.locale) }}
```

Can anybody explain me how I could translate the value of an angularJS variable with the twig translate?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle

Translation of twig is rendered server side, your js is client side. With this bundle you can expose the translations to js. But I have no experience with that bundle and angular.

Comment: thank you for the tip. But I don't want to use another bundle or plugin, if the possible is there.

Answer (score 1):

Use `verbatim` tag. It marks sections as being raw text that should not be parsed.

For exmple:

Create twig variable and affect it at value of angular's variable

```
{% set optionTitle %}
    {% verbatim %} {{ item.optionTitle }}{% endverbatim %} 
{% endset %}
```

Traslatate

```
{{ optionTitle | trans({}, 'option', app.request.locale) }}
```

Now `{{ item.optionTitle }}` will not parsed by twig but by angularjs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I'm using twig / symfony for translation. So i need the value of the angularJS variable in twig. Your snippets doesn't work for me

Comment: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "operator" of value "%" - Comes as error

Comment: the value of optionTitle is then  {{ item.optionTitle }} and he search for the translation for {{ item.optionTitle }} not its value :/

Comment: what do you want to translate excactly ?

Comment: And don't forget to include angulr lib and your angular app

Comment: The value of item.optionTitle is a string out of the database and the translation of the string is in the *.xlf file.

Comment: Where comes from `item.optionTitle`. it's a php variable or angular ?

Comment: item is an temporary angularJS object. I'm using ng-repeat here to list all items

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API endpoint which accepts string to translate

```
/api/translate?string=Active+Option
```

And translate in API controller

```
$translator->trans($string);
```

Then build a simple translation filter in AngularJS

```
angular.filter('apiTranslate', function($http) {
  return function(string) {
    $http.get('/api/translate?string=' + string).then(function (response) {
      return response;
    });
  };
})
```

Keep in mind that there are other solutions which work great with this problem (as suggested BazingaJsTranslationBundle), but you mentioned that you don't want to use libraries, and want to use TWIG to translate.

Answer (score 0):

There are not so much alternatives. 
You need to create something like this in your `html`

```
<script>
   var Global = Global || {};
   Global.translation = {{ catalogue|raw|json_encode }}
</script>
```

In this way you expose globally the translation to your other files.

What is `catalogue`?

From **version 2.6** symfony gives you a way to get the whole translation catalogue exactly in case you need to expose it to your frontend

> In case you want to use the same translation catalogue outside your application (e.g. use translation on the client side), it's possible to fetch raw translation messages. Just specify the required locale

[Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html)

```
$catalogue = $translator->getCatalogue('fr_FR');
$messages = $catalogue->all();
while ($catalogue = $catalogue->getFallbackCatalogue()) {
   $messages = array_replace_recursive($catalogue->all(), $messages);
}
// $messages contains the whole catalogue that you have to pass to frontend
```

So basically your `catalogue` will be shared with the frontend.

**Back to frontend**

Then I created a function that simply returns me the translation by key.

```
function _translate(key) {
    return Global["translation"][key];
}
```